# Where's the application crash dump on an XP SP3 machine?

Tags: windows-xp, minidump

It used to be that an application crash (unhandled exception) would create a mini dump in the %TEMP% folder on an XP machine, but it looks like Microsoft has changed this logic - maybe with an update.

When a user level application or a service crashes, does it still create a mini-dump? Where does it get saved?

PS: I'm not interested in the BSOD, system, or kernel dump. This pertains to a user level application crash that does not bring down Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed the [Debugging Tools For Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009) and used adplus in -crash mode in order to get the dumps I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487440 ?

Ok, then I think you want to enable Dr Watson

http://www.scribd.com/doc/47267084/Capturing-Application-Crash-Dumps

http://serato.com/howtos/scratchlive/1925/how-to-enable-dr-watson

Comment: Sorry, no. I have a C++ Win32 application that crashes on XP SP3. I want to get a mini dump from it so I can investigate the crash. I don't want to send the mini dump to MS and then wait 7 days for it to show up on Winqual so I can then download it and begin my investigation.